# AutoMapper - map string to List<T>

Tags: .net, automapper

I have a "source" class with string property, like

```cs
class Source {
  public string JsonItems {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to map JsonItems to "dest" DTO with property Items

```cs
class Dest {
  public List<Item> Items {get;}
}
```

Please tell me, is it possible?

Comment: What exactly are going to map? `Json` to `Item`?

Comment: You're going to need a ValueConverter

Comment: You need to provide an example of "source" and "dest", because its not clear what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @kosist yes, Json to Items.

Comment: @phuzi i've unsuccessfully tried to do this using valueconverter. because IVauleConverteer's result should be assigned to the propety value, but the Items property has no setter.

Comment: @k0st1x, one more point - may you need to deserialize your `JsonItems`? Then you don't need Automapper. Give the example of `JsonItems ` string, and also structure of `Item` class.

Comment: @kosist yes, i want to deserialize the Items property while automapper is applied, the dto is complex and i've shown the example with single property

Comment: @k0st1x, if you json string contains serialized objects, you need to do mappings in 2 steps. 1. Deserialize your json into class/classes. 2. Then map that class/classes to your dto.